# Loading views from a common XML file

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to have a commons.xml layout file, storing various subviews and being able to inflate the single views by code.

The goal is having being able to load buttons, labels, etc via `findViewById()` from a xml file and being able to add them to a MergeAdapter via `MergeAdapter.addView(View v)`.

```
//the following works
TextView text = new TextView(this);     
text.setText("hellooo");
mMergeAdapter.addView(text);

//but how to instantiate the object from the xml definition ?
TextView text =  **???**  //R.layout.commons.xml, mytextviewid  
text.setText("sigh :(");
mMergeAdapter.addView(text);
```

Commons.xml may be as simple as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/mytextviewid" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"      
    />
    <Button android:id="@+id/mybutton" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"      
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have no special performance requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XMLPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) to parse a resource XML and get a node you need, then use [XML.asAttributeSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Xml.html#asAttributeSet%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser%29) and [this View constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#View%28android.content.Context,%20android.util.AttributeSet%29) to create a new instance of a View manually with configuration from XML